# How to tint an ImageIcon

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, imageicon, tint

How would I tint the icon that is passed through here to be a different color? Say I wanted to take a white image and make it a bit darker. I have looked into BufferedImages and such but I can't seem to find anything that will fit into the setup that I am using. I should also note that I am drawing the images onto a JLabel if that makes a difference.

Here is the source that I am using so that you can get an idea as to what I am working with.

```
public class Icon extends ImageIcon{

    private int scale = 1;
    private boolean mirror = false;

    public Icon(URL url) throws IOException{
        super(ImageIO.read(url));
    }

    public void setScale(int scale){
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        int height = 0, width = this.getIconWidth(), x1 = 1;
        if(mirror || scale != 1){
            height = -this.getIconHeight();
        }
        if(mirror){
            x1 = -1;
        }else{
            width = 0;
        }
        g2.translate(width * scale, height);
        g2.scale(x1 * scale, 1 * scale);
        super.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
    }

    public boolean isMirror() {
        return mirror;
    }    

    public void setMirror(boolean mirror) {
        this.mirror = mirror;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `ColorTintFilter` from the duplicate link above, either directly or modify it to your needs. It will tint your image just fine. However, if you just want to make your image slightly darker, you could just overpaint it with transparent black (ie. `new Color(0x20000000, true)` or similar).

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a new BufferedImage to make the transform into:

```
public BufferedImage colorImage(BufferedImage loadImg, int red, int green, int blue) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(loadImg.getWidth(), loadImg.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics(); 
    Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue, 0 /* alpha needs to be zero */);
    graphics.setXORMode(newColor);
    graphics.drawImage(loadImg, null, 0, 0);
    graphics.dispose();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that before and it doesn't seem to work, even if I set the image to be 100% black, it still makes the colors all weird.