# Swing - new ImageIcon from Color

Tags: java, image, swing, colors, icons

I need to programmatically create an `ImageIcon` with a simple color (let's say blue):

[image: Blue square]

So I started doing this :

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon();
```

Now I am trying to fill my `ImageIcon` with a blue color.

Comment: I think this could be marked duplicate for [How to tint an ImageIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444232/how-to-tint-an-imageicon)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(60, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();

graphics.setPaint(new Color(0, 0, 128));
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [answer Lonely Neuron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137777/4298200), I created a method to create a new `ImageIcon` with the desired size and `Color`:

```
public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(Color color, int width, int height) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
    graphics.setPaint(color);
    graphics.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
    return new ImageIcon(image);
}
```

Call it like so:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = createImageIcon(new Color(0, 0, 128), 60, 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class CreateImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        frm.add(new JLabel(createImage(Color.BLUE, new Dimension(200, 100))));
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Icon createImage(Color c, Dimension size) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }
}
```